# How to produce agenda views from buffers in memory

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, profiler

I've noticed that since my org files have been moved to a network share agenda views take an age (1 minute or more) to produce. This is particularly annoying because I am working on a new view and I have to wait a minute every time I rebuild (I am using sticky views).

How can I force org-mode to just read what is in the buffer rather than communicate across the network which is, I presume, what is slowing the reports.

Limiting the view to the current buffer shows no noticeable difference. (C-c a < ...)

Here are the results from my attempt to use the profiler.

CPU

```
+ org-agenda                                                     1257  72%
+ byte-code                                                       326  18%
+ call-interactively                                              123   7%
  Automatic GC                                                     21   1%
  redisplay_internal (C function)                                   7   0%
+ org-agenda-list                                                   1   0%
+ completing-read                                                   1   0%
```

MEMORY

```
+ call-interactively                                        4,836,708  35%
+ org-agenda                                                3,757,174  27%
+ byte-code                                                 3,091,395  22%
+ org-agenda-prepare-window                                   992,490   7%
+ org-agenda-list                                             687,427   5%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                             121,668   0%
+ org-agenda-prepare                                           24,278   0%
+ mouse-fixup-help-message                                     13,192   0%
+ profiler-report-cpu                                           8,188   0%
+ completing-read                                               6,336   0%
+ read-from-minibuffer                                          5,248   0%
+ read-extended-command                                         4,720   0%
+ list                                                          4,208   0%
+ completing-read-default                                       1,800   0%
+ let*                                                            192   0%
+ concat                                                          192   0%
+ org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command                           96   0%
+ pos-visible-in-window-p                                          40   0%
+ read-char-exclusive                                              40   0%
+ org-fit-window-to-buffer                                         32   0%
```

`elp-results` of org-agenda

```
Function name                                                 Call Count  Elapsed Time  Average Time
org-agenda-redo                                               1           134.932       134.932
org-agenda-prepare                                            1           134.089       134.089
org-agenda-mode                                               1           133.007       133.007
org-agenda-prepare-buffers                                    1           0.814         0.814
org-agenda-files                                              3           0.589         0.1963333333
org-agenda-get-day-entries                                    40          0.259         0.006475
org-agenda-finalize                                           1           0.109         0.109
org-agenda-finalize-entries                                   1           0.079         0.079
org-agenda-highlight-todo                                     108         0.0740000000  0.0006851851
org-agenda-get-todos                                          40          0.07          0.0017500000
org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks                                  1           0.069         0.069
org-agenda-fit-window-to-buffer                               1           0.033         0.033
org-agenda-format-item                                        108         0.008         7.40...e-005
org-agenda-new-marker                                         108         0.004         3.70...e-005
org-agenda-skip                                               111         0.003         2.70...e-005
org-agenda-align-tags                                         1           0.002         0.002
org-agenda-fix-displayed-tags                                 108         0.001         9.25...e-006
org-agenda-check-for-timestamp-as-reason-to-ignore-todo-item  110         0.001         9.09...e-006
org-agenda-mark-header-line                                   2           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-update-agenda-type                                 2           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-prepare-window                                     1           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-span-name                                          5           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-skip-eval                                          220         0.0           0.0
org-agenda-reset-markers                                      1           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-fontify-priorities                                 1           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-get-category-icon                                  108         0.0           0.0
org-agenda-set-mode-name                                      1           0.0           0.0
org-agenda-use-sticky-p                                       1           0.0           0.0
```

How can I debug this further?

How can I identify where the network drive is causing the delay?

Can I force org-mode to just read what is in the buffer rather than communicate across the network?

Comment: I needed a summary to better understand this question because it uses the term buffers in memory instead of open buffers, so here goes:  This is essentially a two-part issue -- the reason for the question, and the question itself.  It appears that the O.P. is interested in a workaround to the time-consumption problem by restricting an agenda view to *only* open buffers, so that Emacs does not attempt to locate and open other agenda files that may be located on a network.  However, the O.P. would also be interested in a fix so that a workaround is not needed.

Comment: Strangely, all the buffers are currently open in memory. Furthermore, it appears that changing init.el to include this (setq org-startup-folded nil) seems to have resolved the issue upon rebooting emacs.